# How to use Java lambdas in Scala

Tags: java, scala, lambda, scala-java-interop

I have the following code:

```
source
    .mapValues(value -> value + " Stream it!!!")
    .print(Printed.toSysOut());
```

as you can see, `mapValues` expects a lambda expression.

Now, I am using Java library but the application is written in Scala. How to pass Scala lambda to Java code?

I tried the following:

```
source
  .mapValues(value => value + "hello")
  .print(Printed.toSysOut)
```

But the compiler complains:

```
[error]   (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed[String,?0(in value x$1)])Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: String, _ >: ?0(in value x$1), String])Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: String)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed[Nothing,Nothing])
[error]       .print(Printed.toSysOut)
[error]        ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Nov 19, 2017 7:53:44 PM
```

Comment: Generally Scala is more type strict than Java so quite often you need to specify the generic type parameter when calling Java function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message lists the types of arguments that `print` supports. One of them is:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed[String,?0(in value x$1)]
```

From the error message you can see that you're providing `Printed.toSysOut` with a type of:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed[Nothing,Nothing]
```

[According to the Kafka 1 javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/Printed.html#toSysOut--) (`Printed` was not present in Kafka 1.1), `toSysOut` is defined as:

```
public static <K,V> Printed<K,V> toSysOut()
```

So the answer problem is that Scala is inferring `K` and `V` with types of `Nothing`. You need to provide the types explicitly.

The following will probably work:

```
source
  .mapValues[String](value -> value + " Stream it!!!")
  .print(Printed.toSysOut[String,String])
```

Comment: In 2.11 this line probably will not compile:  `.mapValues(value => value + "hello")`.

Comment: I've tried as you said, but the compiler still says `[error]   (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed[String,?0(in value x$1)])Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper[_ >: String, _ >: ?0(in value x$1), String])Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: String)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Printed[String,String])
[error]       .print(Printed.toSysOut[String, String])
[error]        ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed`

Comment: Scala may be having trouble inferring the `KStream` type after the call to `mapValues`. [According to the javadocs for `mapValues` you can supply a type to make this clearer](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#mapValues-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueMapper-). Can you try something like `.mapValues[String](...)` to help the Scala compiler work out the type?

Comment: You save my day. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 14):

It depends on your version of Scala.

In 2.12 Scala functions can be used in places where Java functions are expected and vice versa.

*App1.java*

```
import java.util.function.Function;

public class App1 {
    public static void method(Function<String, String> function) {
        System.out.println(function.apply("a"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.method1((String s) -> s.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

*App.scala*

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    App1.method((s: String) => s.toUpperCase)
  }

  def method1(function: String => String): Unit = {
    println(function("xyz"))
  }
}
```

In 2.11 you can use `scala-java8-compat`

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-java8-compat" % "0.8.0"
```

*App1.java*

```
import java.util.function.Function;
import static scala.compat.java8.JFunction.func;

public class App1 {
    public static void method(Function<String, String> function) {
        System.out.println(function.apply("a"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        App.method1(func((String s) -> s.toUpperCase()));
    }
}
```

*App.scala*

```
import scala.compat.java8.FunctionConverters._

object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    App1.method(((s: String) => s.toUpperCase).asJava)
  }

  def method1(function: String => String): Unit = {
    println(function("xyz"))
  }
}
```

Alternatively in 2.11 in Scala you can [define implicit converters](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/231430/193435) between `java.util.function.Function` and `scala.Function1`.

So if you use 2.11 try

```
source
  .mapValues((value => value + "hello").asJava)
  .print(Printed.toSysOut)
```

or

```
source
  .mapValues(((value: String) => value + "hello").asJava)
  .print(Printed.toSysOut[String, String])
```