# How to invoke scala method containing functional parmeter in java?

Tags: java, scala, slamdata

env:

```
java:1.8.0_201
scala:2.11.8
IDE: IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.5 (Ultimate Edition) (Build #IU-183.5912.21)
Intellij Scala plugin:V2018.3.6
```

I have a class method like this

```
class ScalaA {
  def cal(op: () => String): String = {
    op.apply()
  }
}
```

And I want to invoke method `cal`, my first try is  like this

```
public class JavaB {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ScalaA().cal(() -> "Hello");

  }
}
```

But an compile error occured:

```
Error:(9, 22) java: incompatible types: scala.Function0 is not a functional interface
    multiple non-overriding abstract methods found in interface scala.Function0
```

Then I try to invoke method `cal` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ScalaA().cal(new Function0<String>() {
      @Override
      public String apply() {
        return "aa";
      }
    });
  }
```

But there is still a compile error

Error:(9, 46) java:  is not abstract and does not override abstract method apply$mcV$sp() in scala.Function0

It seems method apply$mcV$sp() doesn't implemented, but I don't see a method named `apply$mcV$sp()` in `scala.Function0`

```
trait Function0[@specialized(Specializable.Primitives) +R] extends AnyRef { self =>
  /** Apply the body of this function to the arguments.
   *  @return   the result of function application.
   */
  def apply(): R

  override def toString() = "<function0>"
}
```

,
what should I do to solve this problem, could you give me some suggesitions, thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not familiar with scala and functional arguments, but I wish all questions on SO could be written in such a high quality. This is understandable, it has all the codes to reproduce. It is well written. Thumbs up.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I might be wrong ... but it seems your linked question asks the other way round: How to provide a Scala function for a Java method that expects an instance of a functional interface as an argument.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose The question contains answers for both directions: Java to Scala and Scala to Java.

Comment: @刘思凡 I can't reproduce your error. With Scala 2.12.8 + JDK 1.8.0_162 `ScalaA` and `JavaB` compile without errors.

Comment: @刘思凡 What are your versions?

Comment: Ok, it seems you use 2.11.

Comment: @DmytroMitin My java version is 1.8.0_201 and scala version is 2.11.8, I'll add them to  the question later.

Comment: @刘思凡 Either use 2.12 or in 2.11 use `scala.compat.java8.JFunction.func` from `scala-java8-compat`. Deatils are here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47381315/5249621

Comment: It's useful and make sense,thank you very much!

Comment: @刘思凡 Regarding your second approach, you can't see `apply$mcV$sp()`  because this method is auto-generated by Scala compiler (as most of methods with dollar sign in their names). Method `apply$mcV$sp()` is for primitives and generated because of annotation `@specialized` in `Function0`. The following code compiles: https://gist.github.com/DmytroMitin/d8ac6103c6339091ebd8e11446f4077d

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Thank you for your encouragement!  But maybe I should do more search before asking a question.