# How to call Scala curry functions from Java with Generics

Tags: java, scala, generics, currying, scala-java-interop

A *Scala* code has a retry mechanism which is based on currying function:

```scala
object RetryUtil {

  def retry[T](retry: Int, timeout: FiniteDuration)(exc: => T): T = {
  //
  }
}
```

I want to call this code from Java (8), which use generics:

```java
public class SuperService {

    public <T> T call(Data<T> data) {
     // I want to call internalCall from here, with the Scala retry mechanism from before.
    }

    private <T> T internalCall(DataWithResult<T> data) {
    }
}
```

How should it be done?

Thanks.

Comment: `.apply`, I believe. Decompile the bytecode and see for yourself, if you're ever unsure of how Scala code gets desugared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For

```java
private <T> T internalCall(TransactionWithResult<T> data) {
  return null;
}

private void internalCall2(TransactionWithoutResult data) {
}
```

try

```java
public <T> T call(Data<T> data) {
  RetryUtil.retry(3, new FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES), () -> { internalCall2(data); return null; });

  return RetryUtil.retry(3, new FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES), () -> internalCall(data));
}
```

Parameters from multiple parameter lists in Scala should be seen in Java as parameters of a single parameter list.

Scala and Java functions should be interchangeable (since Scala 2.12)

[How to use Java lambdas in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47380774/how-to-use-java-lambdas-in-scala) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/47381315/5249621)

By-name parameters `=> T` should be seen as no-arg functions `() => T`.

I assumed that `Data` implements `TransactionWithResult` and `TransactionWithoutResult`, so `Data` can be used where `TransactionWithResult` or `TransactionWithoutResult` is expected, otherwise the code should be fixed.

Comment: Thanks! And if the method I want to have retry with, `internalCall`, returns `void`?

Comment: Just to elaborate - I have an additional method like `internalCall`, let's call it `internalCall2`, that defined as `private void internalCall(DataWithoutResult data)`, and I need to call it with the retry as well, but it expects to return the `T`. What is the most elegant way to overcome it? Thanks.

Comment: @Johnny Try `RetryUtil.retry(3, new FiniteDuration(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES), () -> { internalCall2(data); return null; });`. And then `return null;` if necessary.